# Get active image URL in slide show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have bellow slide show

### SlideShow

[SlideShow](https://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery-with-vertical-thumbnail.slider)

I have a button and i want when i click that button get the currently showing image URL and use it for my projects.
but i don't know how to get that URL. 
any suggestion ?

Comment: you should delete the comments and add them into the original post before you get downvoted

Comment: pleae create a complete and verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve